# Timing issue with Algolia and VueJs when customising the refinement list

Tags: javascript, vue.js, algolia

I am using Algolia to build up a refinement list of filters, and I have customized the algolia instance to display facets with no matches: [Algolia docs on displaying facets with no matches](https://www.algolia.com/doc/guides/building-search-ui/widgets/customize-an-existing-widget/vue/#display-facets-with-no-matches)

The issue I am having is that in the mounted function in VueJs Algolia is building up the refinement list, and then doing some magic to build the Dom. I am having an issue where I am trying to append a CSS class to these elements in the same mounted function but the NodeList I am working on is constantly returning `[]` empty.

My solution is completely working when typing, and when using the refinement list, but its not working on page reload as the timing of things is out of sync.

```
  mounted() {
    this.searchClient
      .searchForFacetValues([
        {
          indexName: this.indexName,
          params: {
            facetName: this.brandAttribute,
            facetQuery: '',
            maxFacetHits: this.brandLimit,
          },
        },
      ])
      .then(([{ facetHits }]) => {
        this.initialFacets.push(
          ...facetHits.map(facet => ({
            ...facet,
            label: facet.value,
            value: facet.value,
            isRefined: false,
            count: 0,
          }))
        );
      });

      console.log(this.$el.querySelectorAll(".ais-RefinementList-list .ais-RefinementList-count"));  //Returns empty

      setTimeout(() => {
        console.log(this.$el.querySelectorAll(".ais-RefinementList-list .ais-RefinementList-count")); //Is populated
      }, 5000);
  },
```

I have set a timeout to prove this is a timing issue. Inside my timeout The nodelist is returning as expected, and I can add my CSS class, but how long do I wait? I don't believe this is a correct solution

I have tried all VueJs lifecycle hooks and in all the NodeList is returning null.

What I need is:

After the page has completly loaded, loop over my nodeList and Add CSS. The way I am doing this is:

```
document.querySelectorAll(".ais-RefinementList-list .ais-RefinementList-count").forEach(
        function(x) {

          if(x.innerHTML == 0) {
            x.parentElement.style.backgroundColor = "red"
          } else {
            x.parentElement.style.backgroundColor = "white"
          }
        }
      );
```

Working Solution:
[image: Working solution:]

Page Refresh, timing issue:
[image: timing issue]

Putting code in timeout:

```
setTimeout(() => {
        this.$el.querySelectorAll(".ais-RefinementList-list .ais-RefinementList-count").forEach(
          function(x) {

            if(x.innerHTML == 0) {
              x.parentElement.style.backgroundColor = "red"
            } else {
              x.parentElement.style.backgroundColor = "white"
            }
          }
        );
      }, 5000);
```

Gives this solution after 5 seconds: Working:

[image: 5 second delay]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to overcome this with the solution of customizing the UI: [Algolia docs, customizing the UI](https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-reference/widgets/panel/vue/#customize-the-ui)

I completly overwrote my Refinement list, and conditionally added the needed classes using the :style binding directive.

```
<ais-refinement-list
  attribute="ParentPageTitle"
  :transformItems="transformItems"
>

  <label 
    slot="item"
    slot-scope="{ item }"
    class="ais-RefinementList-label"
    :style="[item.count ? {'background-color' : 'white'} : {'background-color' : 'red'}]"
  >
    <input type="checkbox" class="ais-RefinementList-checkbox">
    <span class="ais-RefinementList-labelText">{{item.value}}</span>
  </label>
</ais-refinement-list>
```

CSS is now able to correctly style the component on runtime, and the timing issue has been resolved